# Deseo contar la cantidad de veces que aparece un dato en una columna en R

Tags: r

Tengo una variable en un data frame que tiene 2 millones de filas y alrededor de 50,000 diferentes valores, deseo saber la cantidad de NULL que existen en esta columna, usé table(data$variable) el problema es que al ser 50,000 diferentes valores me muestra los primeros 100 únicamente y omite los restantes, además solo me interesa conocer la cantidad de NULL, ¿cómo puedo consultar cuantos NULL existen en esta columna?

Comment: Intenta con summarise_all(datos, funs(sum(is.na(.))))

Comment: Sería mejor si colocas cómo defines el dataframe

Answer (score 3):

Entendiendo que `"NULL"` es una cadena, puedes aprovechar que

```
data$variable == "NULL"
```

te retorna un vector lógico, dónde los `TRUE` serían las filas dónde efectivamente se cumple la condición mencionada. Gracias a la coerción que hace R del valor lógico `TRUE` a 1 (`FALSE` sería 0), otra forma super simple es usar directamente `sum()`:

```
sum(data$variable == "NULL")
```

Comment: Funciona igual de bien, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que "NULL" es una cadena de caracteres, de lo contrario esas filas no existirían. En ese caso con R base podrías hacer algo así:

```
length(data$variable[data$variable == "NULL"])
```

Eso te da el largo del vector subconjunto de `data$variable` cuando `data$variable`  es igual a la cadena de caracteres `"NULL"`.

Si no funciona sería importante que pusieras en la pregunta un ejemplo de los datos, para ver que tipo de variable es (character, factor, etc.) y a qué tipo de valor remite NULL.

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente, gracias. En efecto "NULL" es una cadena de caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Se pueden transformar valores NA a 0 en R y nos sirve para aplicar funciones a data.frame con la función sapply.

Ejemplo:

```
x=c(1,23,5,9,0,NA)
y=c(5,45,NA,78,NA,34)

dataf=data.frame(cbind(x,y))
mean(dataf$x,na.rm=TRUE)
mean(dataf$y,na.rm=TRUE)
#Podría interesarnos tener en cuenta los NAs
sum(dataf$x,na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(dataf)
sum(dataf$y,na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(dataf)
```

En este caso tenemos un data.frame con dos variables que contienen valores perdidos, deseamos crear una función que  pase estos valores a 0 y aplicarlo al data.frame de partida:

```
haz.cero.na=function(x){
ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)}
dataf.2=data.frame(sapply(dataf,haz.cero.na))
dataf
dataf.2
```